# Is my image caching process going to leak memory?

Tags: android, listview, caching, android-activity

I have an object that overwrites the `Application` object.  In it, I have a member variable which is a `LongSparseArray` where the key is some identifier of type `long` and the value is an object with 2 member variables: a `Bitmap` and a `long` which is used as a timestamp.

This is my global image cache.  Occasionally, a function is ran that looks at the timestamps and ages things that are over an hour old.

By "age" I mean that it removes that entire entry from the `LongSparseArray`.

Here is my question:

Suppose I have an `Activity` with a `ListView`.  Each row in the `ListView` has an `ImageView` that is populated with an image from the cache.

```
Bitmap image = ((MyApp)getApplicationContext()).getImage(id);
holder.imgImage.setImageBitmap(image);
```

Now, suppose the user clicks some button which takes them to a new `Activity`.  While on this new `Activity`, the image previously assigned to a row in the `ListView` in the previous `Activity` ages.

So, to recap, that `Bitmap` key/value entry now no longer exists in the global `LongSparseArray`.

Is that `Bitmap` really able to be reclaimed by Java?  Isn't it still being referred to by the `ImageView` in the `ListView` of the previous `Activity`?  Assuming, of course, that Android hasn't reclaimed the memory used by that `Activity`.

The reason I'm asking about this is my previous aging function would also call `.Recycle()` on the `Bitmap`.  In this scenario, when the user hit the back button and returned to the previous `Activity` which was using that `Bitmap`, the application would crash, presumably because that `Bitmap` was not only missing from the cache, but also from memory.  So I just removed the `.Recycle()` call.

By the way, once the `Bitmap` is removed from the cache, and an object with that id shows up on screen again, the application will download the `Bitmap` again and place it in the cache.  If the previous one stayed in memory, you could see how this would present a problem.

Also, does anyone have any ideas for a more effective solution?

What would happen if I set `myImageView.setDrawingCacheEnabled(false);`?

There are 2 `Activities` which use this image caching.  One is a search screen that displays a list of items (and their images) after the user performs a search.  The other is a list of those items the user has then selected to keep.

Comment: O' CommonsWare, O' CommonsWare, where art thou CommonsWare?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Issue**: Once [recycle()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Bitmap.html#recycle()) method is called on a bitmap, the bitmap should never be used again. If an attempt is made to draw the bitmap, then an exception will be thrown. From [docs](http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/manage-memory.html):

> You should use recycle() only when you are sure that the bitmap is no
>   longer being used. If you call recycle() and later attempt to draw the
>   bitmap, you will get the error: "Canvas: trying to use a recycled
>   bitmap".

In this specific case, you have recycled the bitmap, but the `ListView` item's `ImageView` has a strong reference to the bitmap. When you return to the Activity, the ListView item attempts to draw the bitmap, hence the exception is thrown.

**Bitmap memory management**: Prior to `Android 2.3.3`, the backing pixel data of a bitmap was stored in native memory and bitmap itself in Dalvik memory. Hence to release the native memory, `recycle` method has to be called.

Here is `Bitmap.recycle` function definition:

```
    public void recycle() {
        if (!mRecycled) {
            if (nativeRecycle(mNativeBitmap)) {
                // return value indicates whether native pixel object was actually recycled.
                // false indicates that it is still in use at the native level and these
                // objects should not be collected now. They will be collected later when the
                // Bitmap itself is collected.
                mBuffer = null;
                mNinePatchChunk = null;
            }
            mRecycled = true;
        }
    }
```

Post `Android 3.0`, the backing pixel data is also stored in Dalvik memory. When the bitmap is no longer required, we need to ensure we don't hold any strong reference to the bitmap, so that it is garbage collected.

**Solution**: If you are still supporting `Android 2.3.3` and lower version, you still need to use `recycle` to release the bitmap.

You can use reference counting to track whether the bitmap is currently being referenced by the ListView item, so that even it is aged, you don't call `recycle` on the bitmap.

ListView adapater's `getView` method is the place where the bitmap is assigned to the ImageView. Here you increment the reference count. You can attach [setRecyclerListener](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AbsListView.html#setRecyclerListener(android.widget.AbsListView.RecyclerListener)) to the ListView to know whenever the listview item is put into recycle bin. This is the place you would decrement the reference count of the bitmap. The aging function need to recycle the bitmap only if the reference count is zero.

You can also consider using [LruCache](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/LruCache.html) for caching, as mentioned in [docs](http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/cache-bitmap.html).

**setDrawingCacheEnabled**: By calling this method with true param, the next call to `getDrawingCache` will draw the view to a bitmap. The bitmap version of view can be rendered on to the screen. Since it is just a bitmap, we cannot interact with it as done with an actual view. Couple of use cases are:

- When `ListView` is being scrolled, the bitmap of the displayed items view is captured and rendered. So that the views being scrolled don't undergo measure and layout pass.
- View hierarchy feature in DDMS.

Comment: I am considering switching to an `LruCache`, but I don't understand how this avoids the process you are describing above.  You can see my concerns [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25628734/implementing-a-global-lrucache-vs-many-local-lrucaches).  Also, I am currently still supporting 2.3.3, though this could change soon.

Comment: @Andrew I've answered your concerns [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/25634577/2083078).

Comment: Thank you for your responses, Manish.

Answer (score 0):

> Is that Bitmap really able to be reclaimed by Java? Isn't it still
>   being referred to by the ImageView in the ListView of the previous
>   Activity? Assuming, of course, that Android hasn't reclaimed the
>   memory used by that Activity.

The `Bitmap` is stilled used in the `ListView` (a strong reference) so dalvik can't reclaim its memory.

Apparently you can't call `recycle` on the Bitmap or bad things will happen(app crash, e.g.).

> What would happen if I set myImageView.setDrawingCacheEnabled(false);?

If you disable drawing cache, every time your view needs to be redrawn, the `onDraw` method will be called.I'm not very familiar with `ImageView` , you can go and read its source for a deep understanding.
(Note: the usage of drawing cache is different when hardware accerleration is enabled/disabled, here I just assume you're using software rendering).

For the solution, you can try the following:

1. when the Bitmap cache become stale, you remove it from the cache array(and then you app will try to get a new one, I think).
2. In `ListView.getView`, you can check whether currently used Bitmap ages. It should be easy because you know the timestamp when you call `setImageBitmap` the first time and the latest timestamp. If they are not same, you call `setImageBitmap` again using the new Bitmap and the old one will be reclaimed.

Wish this helps.

Comment: Every time `getView()` is called, it hits the cache for the image.  The problem is, what if an `Activity` that is in the middle of the `Activity` stack has an `ImageView` using one of the old images that has been popped off the cache?  Is there a way, during `onPause()` or something, that I could tell all of the `Activity`'s `ImageView`s to stop pointing to the bitmap?

Comment: This seems like an issue many, many, many, many apps should have.  So how are they all solving it?  Why have I never seen this discussed before?

Answer (score 0):

Regarding, "Also, does anyone have any ideas for a more effective solution?"

The Picasso library would help solve the problems you are facing http://square.github.io/picasso/

Picasso is "A powerful image downloading and caching library for Android"

"Many common pitfalls of image loading on Android are handled automatically by Picasso:

- Handling ImageView recycling and download cancelation in an adapter.
- Automatic memory and disk caching."