# Implementing a global LruCache vs many local LruCaches

Tags: android, imageview, android-lru-cache

Several `Activity`s in my app display images in a `ListView` where each row of the `ListView` contains an `ImageView`.

An example of this would be a search screen where the user searches, gets results, and a picture of each result is shown.

I'm trying to weigh the cost/benefits of implementing a global `LruCache` vs having each `Activity` contain its own local `LruCache`.

Here are my two main problems.  Both revolve around the fact that my app is quite large, meaning there are quite a few screens which show these images.  Also, my app has the popular side menu way of navigating.  Because of this, I could open the menu, tap `Activity B`, open the menu, tap `Activity A`, open the menu... etc. and create an `Activity` stack of ABABABABABABABAB indefinitely.

**Global**

Won't `Activity`s with `ImageView`s using `Bitmap`s from a global `LruCache` contain references to these `Bitmaps`?  Suppose the user navigates away from this `Activity` by clicking some `Button`.  That `Activity` is now on the `Activity` stack and still holds references to those `Bitmaps`.  If the `LruCache` pops a `Bitmap` off, can that `Bitmap` really be reclaimed when an `ImageView` in some `Activity` on the stack holds a reference to it?

I had previously created my own custom cache.  If I called `recycle()` on a `Bitmap` and then the user hit the back button to go back to some `Activity` on the stack that contained an `ImageView` set to that `Bitmap`, the app would crash.  This is why I believe `ImageView`s on `Activity`s on the stack still hold references to `Bitmap`s.

**Local**

As I mentioned earlier.  My app is quite large, and side menu style of navigation allows the user to create rather large `Activity` stacks.  This would create a lot of `LruCache`s.  And, since you have to declare the size of the `LruCache` when you initialize it, there wouldn't seem to be any good way of picking a size.

Thoughts?  Suggestions?

At this point I think I have to do global, but I don't know how to solve the `Activity` stack reference problem.  I can't imagine this isn't a problem many apps haven't run into.  I don't know why I'm not finding information about it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I'm trying to weigh the cost/benefits of implementing a global
>   LruCache vs having each Activity contain its own local LruCache.

Global LruCache is the way to move forward, since the same set of bitmaps might be referred in different activity instances. The LruCache can be defined part of [Application](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Application.html). If the activity stack can host multiple instances of the same activity (like ABABABAB..), then creating a LruCache locally in that activity will be a bad idea. Very soon Out Of Memory situtation will be reached, as LruCache in each activity instance reserves the defined amount of memory in Dalvik VM. Assume, application memory is 32Mb and you decide LruCache size as 4Mb i.e. 1/8th. Now when we create nearly 7 instances of Activity A, then memory consumption will go to 7*4=28Mb, that itself might trigger OOM.

> Won't Activitys with ImageViews using Bitmaps from a global LruCache
>   contain references to these Bitmaps?

Yes ImageView will also have a strong reference to the bitmap. If the reference is maintained in LruCache, then the reference count will be 2 at that moment.

> If the LruCache pops a Bitmap off, can that Bitmap really be reclaimed
>   when an ImageView in some Activity on the stack holds a reference to
>   it?

No the bitmap memory can't be reclaimed, as still some ImageView is have a strong reference to it.

> At this point I think I have to do global, but I don't know how to
>   solve the Activity stack reference problem.

LruCache main role is holding strong reference to the bitmap which are more frequently used. So that if there is no strong reference held by any ImageView, the bitmap is prevented from being garbage collected.

Also remember, for Android 2.3.3 and lower versions, you need to implement reference counting mechanism, in order to recycle the bitmaps.

Comment: Thank you for your response.  Is there a solution to: `No the bitmap memory can't be reclaimed, as still some ImageView is have a strong reference to it`?  This seems like a problem.  Maybe, in onPause(), pointing all ImageViews to some other image?